# In node.js app, mdkirSync('mydir',700) results in permission d-w------T

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions, mkdir, fs

I have a `node.js` application creating a local directory in order to dump content. It uses the `fs` module:

```
fs.mkdirSync(pathToDir, 700);
```

The directory is indeed created locally on Openshift, but it has permissions:

```
d-w------T
```

How can I set the permission I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use octal number to set the right permissions:

```
fs.mkdirSync(pathToDir, 0700);
```